# HttpCacheGenerateKeyEvent & Session

Tags: shopware6

We would like to display different prices depending on a selected pickup store.
The store selection is implemented with our plugins StoreLocator and StorePickup and stored in the session.

We can control the caching behavior as described in https://shyim.me/blog/deep-dive-caching-shopware6/ via a cache key modification in the "HttpCacheGenerateKeyEvent" event.
Unfortunately, when the mentioned event is fired, the session has not yet started and we cannot access the selected store. How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste from [`StorefrontSubscriber`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/89e9f80f15643bd6980b3e87c5cbe29bdccae5c4/src/Storefront/Framework/Routing/StorefrontSubscriber.php#L91) for starting the session. If the session is not yet created, inject `session_factory` and create it on the spot.

```php
private \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionFactoryInterface $sessionFactory;

// ...

$request = $event->getRequest();

if (!$request->attributes->get(SalesChannelRequest::ATTRIBUTE_IS_SALES_CHANNEL_REQUEST)) {
    return;
}

if (!$request->hasSession()) {
   $request->setSession($this->sessionFactory->createSession());
}

$session = $request->getSession();

if (!$session->isStarted()) {
    $session->setName('session-');
    $session->start();
    $session->set('sessionId', $session->getId());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesnt work.
`$this->requestStack->getMainRequest()` is null.

Comment: Use `HttpCacheGenerateKeyEvent::getRequest`

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesnt work either.

`$request->hasSession()` is false

In the event is no request available.

Comment: Then just inject `session_factory` and create it on the spot 